# Cache Appliance for ISP

Tags: networking, cache, isp

We want to invest in a Cache Appliance solution to reduce our bandwidth and improve the user experience.

Which cache appliance do you recommend? So far I have these candidates CacheBOX and CacheMara.

We want a full commercial product (that includes hardware) so we can get a full-package support as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to spend money on an "appliance box" which will just be an Atom Server, running Debian 6 and Squid?

Just get a cheap server, run Debian 6 on it, and install Squid.

Seriously.  Appliance boxes aren't all they're cracked up to be, generally.  Sure, there's "support", which is *expensive*.  There's also the risk that they won't be quite as pro-active as they could be on updates, and security patches, and your new-fangled appliance box, actually becomes a weak point in your network.  You won't know about this, because it's a hands-off black box.

Screw the appliances.  Get a server. Run Squid on it.  If you need support, use the community, or hire a contract sysadmin.